# Best way to work with weekends and holidays in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database that contains a sell table. This sell table contains a column with sell date. My problem is: I want to show only workdays in my search.

The table simplified:

```
# select * from sells;
 id |  emission  
----+------------
  1 | 2019-11-19
  2 | 2019-11-20
  3 | 2019-11-21
  4 | 2019-11-23
  5 | 2019-11-24
  6 | 2019-11-25
  7 | 2019-11-22
(7 rows)
```

I have another table with holidays:

```
postgres=# select * from holidays;
 id |  holiday   
----+------------
  1 | 2019-11-20
  2 | 2019-11-22
(2 rows)
```

Actually, what I do the following to get only workdays:

```
    SELECT sells.id,
           EXTRACT(DOW FROM emission), 
           CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DOW FROM emission)=6 
                THEN emission+'2 days'::interval 
                WHEN EXTRACT(DOW FROM emission)=0 
                THEN emission+'1 day'::interval 
                WHEN holiday is not null
                THEN emission+'1 day'::interval
                ELSE emission
            END
     FROM sells
LEFT JOIN holidays ON (holiday=emission);

 id | date_part |      emission       
----+-----------+---------------------
  1 |         2 | 2019-11-19 00:00:00
  2 |         3 | 2019-11-21 00:00:00
  3 |         4 | 2019-11-21 00:00:00
  7 |         5 | 2019-11-23 00:00:00
  4 |         6 | 2019-11-25 00:00:00
  5 |         0 | 2019-11-25 00:00:00
  6 |         1 | 2019-11-25 00:00:00
(7 rows)
```

Two concerns about this method:

1. If the holiday is in friday, next one date is saturday so, it's a problem, as seen on the `id=7` on last query
2. Optimization. The sells table have 5 million lines, in this case, we have issues with performance. Adding indexes in this approach - i believe - will not work because two tables are used in `CASE` statement.

One option is create a new column with default trigger that generates the correct date but, if a new holiday is added to holidays table?

I'm using **postgresql-10** in **ubuntu**. The data on warehouse are supplied by a sink connector in apache Kafka (it's ok to add new columns on table, if needed.

Comment: I think the easiest solution will be to create a calendar table that contains one row for each day for e.g. the next 10 years. Then you can mark each row as holiday or weekday (note that "weekday" is not necessary Monday till Friday across the world) and you can include a column with the "next day" for each of those. Calculating that once for the 10 years isn't really that hard and can even be done using procedural code. But _using_ that will makes things in your queries extremely easy - you just join on the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION (Suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name in comments:)**

I created a table "holidays":

```
CREATE TABLE holiday (holiday date, name varchar, next_workday date)
```

Created an insert statement for the next 27 years (found a list on internet for local holidays - here I expect that each country have your own holidays, so, for each country a specific list need to be created) and, before that, run this query (considered Saturday and Sunday as weekend, another case that can differ from country to country).

```
UPDATE holiday set next_workday=
(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DOW FROM holiday+'1 day'::interval)=6 
      THEN holiday+'3 days'::interval 
      WHEN EXTRACT(DOW FROM holiday+'1 day':: interval)=0 
      THEN holiday+'1 day'::interval 
      ELSE (holiday+'1 day'::interval)::date 
   END)::date;
```

And, modified the main select:

```
SELECT sells.id,
           EXTRACT(DOW FROM COALESCE(next_workday, emission)), 
           CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DOW FROM COALESCE(next_workday, emission))=6 
                THEN emission+'2 days'::interval 
                WHEN EXTRACT(DOW FROM COALESCE(next_workday, emission))=0 
                THEN emission+'1 day'::interval 
                ELSE COALESCE(next_workday, emission)
            END
     FROM sells
LEFT JOIN holidays ON (holiday=emission);
```

Comment: I think your `UPDATE` statement needs Friday (DOW = 5) to do +3 days, Saturday  (DOW = 6) to do +2 days, and all others to do +1 days.

Comment: Makes sense. One thing that are not controlled here. If we heve two holidays, one in friday and one in monday, in sequence. The algorithm above will fail.

Comment: In the US, that's not an issue, unless Day after Thanksgiving is considered a company holiday. In other countries it might be, e.g. in Denmark, Easter is Thursday, Friday, *and* Monday, so +5 from Thursday.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a 2-year + old post, but I would like to add my 2 cents here for the people who looking for a similar type of issue while finding the next working days or working days for their calendars.
this is not exactly matching with the requirement But this can give you some idea.

Solution:
Dynamically creating the weekends through Postgres generate_series function and union with the calendar table to identify the working date.

The below query can generate weekends

> ```
>      SELECT   date_trunc('day', dd)::date WEEKENDS FROM   generate_series
>     ( 'Date1'::timestamp 
>     , 'Date2'::timestamp
>     , '1 day'::interval) dd
>    where EXTRACT(ISODOW from dd) in (6,7)
> ```

then your "holidays " calendar can generate the holidays

> select holiday from holidays where holiday::date between Date1 and
> Date2

Now you can combine altogether and you can generate your code by

> ```
> select date_trunc('day', wd)::date WORKING_DATES from  generate_series
>     ( 'Date1'::timestamp 
>     , 'Date2'::timestamp
>     , '1 day'::interval) wd  where wd::date not in ( SELECT  date_trunc('day', dd)::date WEEKENDS FROM   generate_series
>     ( 'Date1'::timestamp 
>     , 'Date2'::timestamp
>     , '1 day'::interval) dd
>    where EXTRACT(ISODOW from dd) in (6,7) 
>    union SELECT  holiday::date FROM holidays where holiday between 'Date1' and 'Date2');
> ```

If you need to get the next working day through a function, you can access this [link](https://itestee.com/2022/05/25/holiday-calendar-with-auto-weekend-generator/)